# pythonで画像の下半分を検出したい

Tags: python, opencv

画像の下半分のみを指定して検出させるコードを教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 1つの文だけだと、記述している内容が少なすぎて、何を基にどんな環境で何をやろうとしてどのような問題が発生しているのか、良く分かりません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を改善して特に具体的な情報を詳細に記述してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: マルチポスト： https://teratail.com/questions/d5lshjpm88y1fb

Answer (score 0):

画像の下半分のみを指定してオブジェクト検出を実行するコードという意味なら、[このノートブック](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/object_detection.ipynb)のrun_detectorを以下のようにしてみてください。

```py
# https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/object_detection.ipynb

def run_detector_half(detector, path):
  img = load_img(path)
  cropped_img = img[img.shape[0]//2:img.shape[0]]
  converted_img  = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(cropped_img, tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, ...]
  start_time = time.time()
  result = detector(converted_img)
  end_time = time.time()

  result = {key:value.numpy() for key,value in result.items()}

  print("Found %d objects." % len(result["detection_scores"]))
  print("Inference time: ", end_time-start_time)

  image_with_boxes = draw_boxes(
      cropped_img.numpy(), result["detection_boxes"],
      result["detection_class_entities"], result["detection_scores"])
  img_np = img.numpy()
  for i, j in enumerate(range(img.shape[0]//2, img.shape[0])):
    img_np[j] = image_with_boxes[i]
  display_image(img_np)
```